# kubectl filter doesn't work with jobs?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to delete jobs using a filter like the following

```
kubectl delete jobs -l ml=""
```

This returns no resources found. However if I do kubectl describe I see

```
Labels:     ml=,job_type=worker,runtime_id=tf-runtime,task_index=0
```

The same filter and command works just fine with the pods created by the job controller.

The command also works just fine my job is tagged with a single label, for example

```
Labels:     ml=
```

So my filter appears to be incorrect when there are other labels on the resource. However, the same set of labels on other resources (services, pods) works just fine with that filter.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this with with kubectl 1.3.0 and I can't reproduce it.  Can you try the latest kubectl?

Comment: Thanks. Here's the version information for the version I used with the original post. kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.4", GitCommit:"3eed1e3be6848b877ff80a93da3785d9034d0a4f", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"3", GitVersion:"v1.3.0", GitCommit:"283137936a498aed572ee22af6774b6fb6e9fd94", GitTreeState:"clean"}
I'll update the post after I upgrade and try again.

Comment: It worked using the version mentioned above which appears to be the latest version installed by gcloud. Not sure what I did wrong before. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually that wasn't it. I updated the question. There appears to be an issue with multiple labels and my filter.

Comment: Same problem appears to happen with kubectl get.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce it using a simple yaml file. I suspect the problem is related to the fact that I'm configuring my own matchSelector. When I tried to set the matchSelector in a yaml file and then do kubectl create -f job_spec.yaml, kubectl complained about an invalid spec.